# Composing a new image

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to find a way where I can crop this image using the center circle as a reference and cut it in half ...

[image]

And take the second half of the image and compose another image like this.

[image]

My attempts:

```
img = Import["c:\\Users\\Leandro\\Desktop\\1.png"];
circ = ImageTake[img, {200, 0}, {375, 1500}]
f = ImageCorrelate[img, circ, NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance];
pos = Binarize[f, 0.2];
cen = Mean[ImageValuePositions[pos, 0]];

Show[img, Epilog -> {Red, Point[cen]}]
```

Anyone have any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdwYs.png"];
center = 3 /. ComponentMeasurements[img, {"Centroid", "MeanCentroidDistance"}]
{left, right} = ImageCrop[img, {center[[1, 1]], Full}, #] & /@ {Right, Left}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and then

```
ImageAssemble[
 ImageCrop[#1, {Full, 
     2 Last[ImageDimensions[left]] - Ceiling@center[[2]]}, #2, Padding -> White] &
       @@@ {{left, Top}, {right, Bottom}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]